# Android: fetch data from server and create listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am really new to android application development and I am trying to create a small app that fetches some json data from server and then create a list view. I got it working with the Array adapter, but now i am trying to create a custom adapter, which is not working, can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<Project> rowItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        String url = "http://192.168.2.2/api/get_projects/?format=json";
        DownloadData downloadata = new DownloadData();
        downloadata.execute(url);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        List<Project> rowItems;
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter;
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
            Dialog.show();

            adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowItems);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

         protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Error = e.getMessage();
                    cancel(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Error = e.getMessage();
                    cancel(true);
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                Dialog.dismiss();
                if (Error != null) {
                    Log.d(Error, Error);

                } else {

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);
                        JSONArray projs = json.getJSONArray("objects");

                        for (int i = 0; i < projs.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject proj = projs.getJSONObject(i);

                            int id = proj.getInt("id");
                            String full_name = proj.getString("full_name");
                            String client = proj.getString("client");
                            Project item = new Project(id, full_name, client);
                            rowItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

CustomBaseAdapter

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Project> rowItems;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Project> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView pk;
    TextView full_name;
    TextView client;
    int position;
}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.pk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pk);
        holder.full_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
        holder.client = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    Project rowItem = (Project) getItem(position);

    holder.pk.setText(rowItem.getPk());
    holder.full_name.setText(rowItem.getFull_name());
    holder.client.setText(rowItem.getClient());

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="pk" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.59"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="full_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/client"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="client"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help...

Comment: +1 for creating your own adapter as a newbie. Many people seem to shy from that. What exactly isn't working as you expect it to? By any chance a null pointer exception?

Comment: hi Cris, it does not give any error in the debug view, but when i start the app it just crashes..

Comment: There's nothing in the logcat? It should be giving you the stacktrace there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you are not inflating the convertView inside your **`getView()`**.

What you need to do is first check if convertView is null or not. If it is, then you need to inflate the layout of each row. If it is not null, then you can happily reuse the old view (without having to inflate it again).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null ) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout. list_item_1, null);
            }
    TextView pk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pk);
    TextView full_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    TextView client = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client);


    Project rowItem = (Project) getItem(position);

    pk.setText(rowItem.getPk());
    full_name.setText(rowItem.getFull_name());
    client.setText(rowItem.getClient());

    return convertView;
}
```

You could also skip the null check and inflate it every time, but it would not reuse the views then and thus the performance would go down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate your custom list item layout. A further optimisation is to start to use the [view holder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
       convertView = Views.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.list_item_1);
    }
    TextView pk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pk);
    TextView full_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    TextView client = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client);


    Project rowItem = (Project) getItem(position);

    pk.setText(rowItem.getPk());
    full_name.setText(rowItem.getFull_name());
    client.setText(rowItem.getClient());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Hi, im getting this error in the logcat `Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1244 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 `